# Simulating a disabled wmode

Tags: flash, flash-builder, pixel, bitmapdata, wmode

Im running into a trouble here.

Here's the thing, I'm making a flash game that uses some pixel techniques like copypixels, bitmapdata, etc.

Im planning to offer the game to FGL (Flash Game License) and I read that they doesn't not allow wmode, and many other portals do the same.

So.. my question is, is my game taking advantage of wmode=gpu?.. how can I run my swf file and disable wmode for sure?, I just want to know if my game will run smothly without that wmode enabled.

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

wmode is about how the browser handles displaying your game inside of an HTML page.  Using "pixel techniques" inside of ActionScript will not change anything - you have to explicitly set this parameter when you embed your plugin.  You can learn about wmode [here](http://www.kaourantin.net/2008/05/what-does-gpu-acceleration-mean.html).

So you can answer your question yourself: Do you set wmode in the HTML you use to embed your SWF in?  Does your game still work when you omit wmode?

Comment: I see, now you mention it, no, seems like I dont use wmode at all, I added a param to my swfobject setting the wmode=gpu, opaque or transparent, and I got no performance variations.. so I think thats conclusive isnt?